# How to change the url being called by javascript without access to the javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service

I have an jQuery('#Frame').animate360 script on page and it calls a file called Profile.xml to  get its settings etc.
Problem is Profile.xml is on Azure Blob and is in uppercase (PROFILE.XML). This means a 404 file not found error.

I can't change filename(Profile.xml) on azure.

The piece of JS that calls the Profile.xml seems to be encrypted in a library (HTML5Loader.js) i.e. The text 'Profile.xml' does not appear in any file and can only be found with chrome debugger in an unnamed file.

My instinct was to use something  like Application_BeginRequest etc to catch a 'call' to  https://storageblabla.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/ALPHA/3DIMAGES/1.010659/Profile.xml
and change it to ...../PROFILE.XML
but it's to late at that stage. It already knows that its a 404.

There must be some access, with code, to a point where a remote url is being called that can be intercepted.

Rekon its a one line fix but I just can't find the right term to search on.

Comment: Why can't change the file name "Profile.xml"? In my opinion, this is the easiest way to fix this type issue.

Comment: 'Cause its uploaded(along with thousands of others) from a system where every file name is auto put to  uppercase. (Ironically to 'solve' the 'case matters' issue with azure blobs)